# .NET MVC ApplicationUser could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm just building a simple login/register page with .net mvc. Everything was going fine until all of a sudden, when I tried to run the register page, it tell me that there is an error in IdentityConfig.cs...

"The type or namespace name 'ApplicationUser' could not be found"

On this page I do have a "using projectname.Models;" - I haven't even looked at this page the entire time.

I'm not even using the Identity stuff, all the login/ register page is just a basic custom version. I have no idea why this has just randomly started happening, when I haven't been using that this whole time. I've tried taking out the code I wrote just before it started, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What type of visual studio template are you using, is it empty one without Authentication?

Comment: ASP.NET web application ... MVC. It just has the template home, about, contact us views

Comment: If you use ASP.NET web application MVC, there is an option to choose authentication (Change Authentication button on right hand side when you select template), I believe you have used default one which is individual User Accounts, then you'll get automatically created Asp.net Identity framework authentication with login, register and other account related pages. That is the part you may got wrong. I think you are using asp.net identity related stuffs without knowing it.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks! Just upon reading the description for each of the authentication buttons... should i check 'no authentication' even if i still want to be loading accounts from my own database in sql server?

Comment: Yes, each template included different set of pre-defined set of functionaries and seems authentication added separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ASP.NET web application MVC, there is an option to choose authentication (Change Authentication button on right hand side when you select template), I believe you have used default one which is individual User Accounts, then you'll get automatically created Asp.net Identity framework authentication with login, register and other account related pages. That is the part you may got wrong. I think you are using asp.net identity related stuffs without knowing it.

**Update :**

Yes, you have to chose it that way, if not you'll get created all identity stuff.